# jQueryFileUpload resize images while directly uploading to S3

Tags: php, image-processing, amazon-s3, jquery-file-upload

I'm using the awesome [jQueryFileUpload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). I'm now uploading directly to S3 simply by changing the server-side option `upload_dir` from my server to s3 like this:

```
    $this->options = array(
        'upload_dir' =>'s3://'.$this->bucket.'/'.$this->prefix,
```

[See the uploadHandler.php for full code.](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php)

That is so easy I was shocked. But there is always a catch and the catch is that now you can't do generate thumbnail server-side.

I think the problem lies with `handle_image_file()` and the `$file_path` for image processing being the S3 url instead of the tmp directory where the file is uploaded to.

Can one process an image in the tmp directory? Or better yet, how can I access the s3 file to do the image processing on that?

Any Help?

Comment: Did you get any answer? I am stuck with this problem. Please reply ASAP.